# Passing class name as parameter to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare return values of different rest api json responses, and i would like to create a method that takes a class name as a paremeter like the following.  I have tried submitting as string and typeof(). would like to know what's the right way to pass ClassName as a parameter or if i should take a different approach.

```
class Employee
{
//different properties
}

class Patient
{
//different properties
}

class Tests
{
    public bool compareValues(ClassName)
    {
        string expectedValues = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var expectedValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName[]>(fileResult, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });        
                //similar thing: call rest api as above.

        //compare logic
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you using an array in the Generic argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called generics. See example below:

```
public bool compareValues<T>(ClassName)
{
    string expectedValues = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    var expectedValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(fileResult, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });        
            //similar thing: call rest api as above.

    //compare logic
}

var employeeResult = compareValues<Employee>();
var patientResult = compareValues<Patient>();
```

Note method signature was changed and it contains `<T>` - a placeholder for class name. This will work if you already know which classes are used in your method. If you have only class name as a string, you have to deserialize your json without specifying concrete class `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)` and work with `JObject` (see Json.Net documentation)

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, I would like to order by like var expectedValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(fileResult, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }).OrderBy(o => o.ID).ToArray();  I would like to pass ID as a parameter also.